Spring Data JPA sort OneToMany by nested entity attribute
I have the following entities:
@Entity
public class Catalog{

   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @OneToMany
   private List<Entry> entries;
}

@Entity
public class Entry{

   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private EntryType type;
}

@Entity
public class EntryType{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   private final String name;
}

When fetching the Catalog I want to sort the entries by their EntryType.
I had the following in the Catalog Entity:
   @OneToMany
   @OrderBy(value = "type.name")
   private List<Entry> entries;

However this results in the following error on compile:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Ordering for ToOneAttributeMapping(NavigableRole[com.company.Entry.type])@1158959071 not supported
Ordering by type.id is supported however anything that would require a second join (Catalog > Entry > EntryType) does not compile.
Is there some way (without manually writing every query) to achieve this?

I have exactly the same issue/question and there does not appear to be a clear answer to this from all the questions I've read.
What I do know is that you can only use the 'dot' notation with @OrderBy when the nested Object property you are sorting is part of an @Embdedded Object.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
